# 3D tensor for Deep Learning : Use a MatrixXd<ArrayXd, Dynamic, Dynamic>

Tags: deep-learning, eigen

I currently use Eigen to do deep learning, and more specifically convolutional neural networks.

You can see an example here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#/media/File:Typical_cnn.png

As each step, a layer could be a convolutional layer (a set of features map), a fully connected layer (a single one-dimensional vector) or anything else.

So I choose `MatrixX<ArrayXd, Dynamic, Dynamic>` to represent my datas.

But when I use it (with matrix product) I have segfaults.

I'm not sure but I think because `ArrayXd` is not a good scalar type for `MatrixX`.

Can I use `ArrayXd` as scalar in Eigen ?

If the answer is no, what can I do ?

Comment: What is `ArrayX`? And you can't use `MatrixXd<ArrayX, Dynamic, Dynamic>`, it should be `Matrix<ArrayXd, Dynamic, Dynamic>` but that probably won't do what you want.

Comment: Yes, it's `MatrixX<ArrayXd, Dynamic, Dynamic>`.

Comment: See kangshiyin's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38552257/2899559).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayXd` is not a good choice to be a scalar type, especially when you want a tensor.

Eigen has tensor support in its dev-branch/v3.3-bata1. You could find the document here.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support

https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/fefbb833ed5442fb21292bdaa3320543868e41b8/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/?at=default#markdown-header-eigen-tensors

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__CXX11__Tensor__Module.html

Comment: Thanks you, I will look at that solution.